# AspNet Core TestServer DbContext.Update(model) doen't save changes

Tags: c#, integration-testing, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I currently try to create an integration test which tests an edit step. Editing works (changes are saved in the database, editing works during normal program usage), but the changes are not "stored" in the test-dbcontext. Therefore, if I get the edited model from the context again, it still has the old values.
Further additions to the dbcontext (AuditChange) are visible in the test method though.

I have tried other databases (Sqlite, InMemoryDatabase), but still the same problem.

Do I miss something, or is this some "funny" bug somewhere?

Regards
Matthias

Somewhat shortened Test Method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task LocalUserCompleteRunHandlingTestAsync() {
        TestServer server = GetTestServer("CompleteRunHandling");
        MySqlDbContext context = server.Host.Services.GetService<MySqlDbContext>();

        try {
            // Creating model and asserting of newly created model removed.

            // Get Edit 
            var editGetResult = await client.GetAsync("/Fruit/Edit/" + fruit.Id);
            Assert.IsTrue(editGetResult.IsSuccessStatusCode);

            // Post Edit
            formTokenVal = await editGetResult.GetAntiForgeryFormToken();
            var editedName = "edited Name";
            var editedComment = "edited Comment";
            var postEditData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            postEditData.Add("Id", fruit.Id.ToString());
            postEditData.Add("Name", editedName);
            postEditData.Add("Comment", editedComment);
            postEditData.Add(formTokenVal.Key, formTokenVal.Value);
            var editPostResult = await client.PostAsync("/Fruit/Edit/" + fruit.Id, new FormUrlEncodedContent(postEditData));
            Assert.AreEqual(302, (int)editPostResult.StatusCode); // If successful, redirect to index.
            context = server.Host.Services.GetService<MySqlDbContext>();
            var editedFruit = context.Fruit.Single(r => r.Id == fruit.Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(editedComment, editedFruit.Comment); // Assert fails, editedFruit.Comment is still the old value.
            Assert.AreEqual(editedName, editedFruit.Name);
            // Further code removed

        } finally {
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        }
    }
```

Controller method:

```
public IActionResult Edit(FruitEditViewModel fruitViewModel) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        Fruit fruit= _context.Fruit.Single(f => f.Id == fruitViewModel.Id);
        _auditTrailService.TakeSnapshotBefore(fruit);

        fruit.Comment = fruitViewModel.Comment;
        fruit.Name = fruitViewModel.Name;
        _context.Fruit.Update(fruit);
        AuditChange auditChange = _auditTrailService.CompareObjects(fruit, GetCurrentUserId(), AuditActionType.Update);
        if (auditChange != null) {
            _context.Add(auditChange);
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(fruitViewModel);
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you're calling `SaveChanges`.

Comment: _context.SaveChanges();    before   return RedirectToAction("Index");

Comment: I have corrected the controller method in this post. SaveChanges is actually called in my program, but got lost somehow when writing / editing the post.